# Is it straightforward to map Arabic script to romanized pronunciation?

Tags: arabic, transliteration, romanization

I am not concerned with the *exact* IPA pronunciation, which might depend on dialect and culture and other factors. Instead I'm wondering if it's relatively straightforward to "transliterate" Arabic into some romanized form.

Right now I have a very basic [Arabic transliterator](https://github.com/mountbuild/snake/blob/master/lib/ara/ula.js). It simply has a mapping of the Arabic character to the desired romanized character. I simply copy/pasted directly from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode) essentially. However, even after accounting for all the consonants and vowels, when I pasted in some Quran data and tried to transliterate it, I quickly ran into 3 problems. 2 were related to [Hamzas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamza) (one on the top, one on the bottom), and another to [Shadda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadda), some other diacritical mark that seems like it can be ignored in the transliteration.

The input was this:

> بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ
>   الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ
>   الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ
>   مَالِكِ يَوْمِ الدِّينِ
>   إِيَّاكَ نَعْبُدُ وَإِيَّاكَ نَسْتَعِينُ
>   اهْدِنَا الصِّرَاطَ الْمُسْتَقِيمَ
>   صِرَاطَ الَّذِينَ أَنْعَمْتَ عَلَيْهِمْ غَيْرِ الْمَغْضُوبِ عَلَيْهِمْ وَلَا الضَّالِّينَ

The output that [Quran411 has](https://www.quran411.com/surah-fatiha) is this:

> Bismillaahir Rahmaanir Raheem
>   Alhamdu lillaahi Rabbil 'aalameen
>   Ar-Rahmaanir-Raheem
>   Maaliki Yawmid-Deen
>   Iyyaaka na'budu wa lyyaaka nasta'een
>   Ihdinas-Siraatal-Mustaqeem
>   Siraatal-lazeena an'amta 'alaihim ghayril-maghdoobi 'alaihim wa lad-daaalleen

You'll notice here though, that for example, the first line in the *transliteration* is 3 words ("Bismillaahir Rahmaanir Raheem"), while the Arabic script is 4 words ("بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ").

When I run my script over this, it doesn't throw an error which is great. All the characters are accounted for so far. But I get [this](https://github.com/mountbuild/snake/blob/master/test/ara/ula.test.js#L38):

> bismi alllahi alr̂r̂aḥmaani alr̂r̂aḥiimi
>   alḥamdu lillahi r̂abbi al'aalamiina
>   alr̂r̂aḥmaani alr̂r̂aḥiimi
>   maaliki yawmi alddiini
>   'iiiiaaka na'budu wa'iiiiaaka nasta'iinu
>   aahdinaa als's'ir̂aat'a almustak̤iima
>   s'ir̂aat'a alalac̣iina 'an'amta 'alayhim ṙayr̂i almaṙd'uubi 'alayhim walaa ald'd'aalliina

First, notice that it matches the *arabic* word number exactly, whereas Quran411 didn't. So that's good (but also obvious given the script). But also notice that some of the words have 3 or 4 letters in a row, like `iiii` in `iiiiaaka`.

Side-by-side comparison to make it a little easier to see is this:

> Bismillaahir Rahmaanir Raheem
>   bismi alllahi alr̂r̂aḥmaani alr̂r̂aḥiimi
>   
>   Alhamdu lillaahi Rabbil 'aalameen
>   alḥamdu lillahi r̂abbi al'aalamiina
>   
>   Ar-Rahmaanir-Raheem
>   alr̂r̂aḥmaani alr̂r̂aḥiimi
>   
>   Maaliki Yawmid-Deen
>   maaliki yawmi alddiini
>   
>   Iyyaaka na'budu wa lyyaaka nasta'een
>   'iiiiaaka na'budu wa'iiiiaaka nasta'iinu
>   
>   Ihdinas-Siraatal-Mustaqeem
>   aahdinaa als's'ir̂aat'a almustak̤iima
>   
>   Siraatal-lazeena an'amta 'alaihim ghayril-maghdoobi 'alaihim wa lad-daaalleen
>   s'ir̂aat'a alalac̣iina 'an'amta 'alayhim ṙayr̂i almaṙd'uubi 'alayhim walaa ald'd'aalliina

Granted, I am not transliterating into the same exact encoding/character system, so there will be slight inherent differences. But also notice that they seem to be combining words in ways which weren't present in the original Arabic script. For example:

> Rabbil 'aalameen
>   r̂abbi al'aalamiina

Mine (2nd one) puts an `al` at the start of the 2nd word, whereas they put just an `l` on the end of the 1st word. Also, there is an `a` at the end of mine.

Another example is this pair:

> Ar-Rahmaanir-Raheem
>   alr̂r̂aḥmaani alr̂r̂aḥiimi

I have `al`, they have `Ar` (ignoring the caps, but `r != l`). They end first word in `r`, mine is missing that `r`. They start the last word in `R`, mine for some reason prefixes it with `al`. I am so confused?! Are they cheating? Of is this just not going to work :(

Now, I would just go about my business and debug this, but I seem to be quite a ways off, even though I followed the directions on Wikipedia (however roughly), to write the simple mappings between characters. I'm wondering if one could point me in the right direction, either pointing out my technical mistakes, or if I need some more education/training around this, where I can look online (what specific free resource)?

Or maybe Quran411 is actually a bad resource, and I could be using something more academic?

Comment: I'm curious about your transliteration: why are you transcribing /r/ with a circumflex, for example?

Comment: (Or rather—there are already [quite a lot of standards for transcribing Arabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Arabic#Comparison_table); why do it differently? I personally don't follow any of those standards exactly, because e.g. it's easier for me to type ħ than ḥ on my keyboard, but I'm curious about your reasoning.)

Comment: The arabic chat one is my favorite standard for sure :D Most natural.

Comment: @Draconis what do you do across languages, do you already have a system?

Comment: Most transcription conventions are going to be language-specific to some extent, unless you want to use IPA or something like that. For example, a lot of Indo-European languages have only a single "rhotic" sound, so it makes sense to transcribe all of those as *r*, even though the actual pronunciation varies wildly.

Comment: Personally, I find it a lot easier to distinguish *k c q* than *k ḳ k̤*, so I'd prefer the IPA. (I like new symbols more than diacritics in general.) But once you get into replacing the IPA that's really deserving of a separate question instead of a comment; the IPA absolutely does have flaws, and if you want to ask what those flaws are and how they might be remedied, that's a viable new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest consulting *A reference grammar of Modern Standard Arabic* by Karin Ryding, which has a detail discussion of the script. Your conversion routine has to include some context-sensitive replacement. For example, alif is not *per se* the vowel *a*, it is a "chair" on which the vowel mark can reside. The other issue is that your source is somewhat at variance with standard practice for transliteration: *bismi llaahi rraḥmaani r̂r̂aḥiimi* would be closer. However, that alternative source doesn't even try to represent the Arabic distinctions (h versus ḥ, s,t,d versus ṣ,ṭ,ḍ, ʕ vs. γ).

You need to first decide what type of transliteration you are after. [This](https://www.loc.gov/catdir/cpso/romanization/arabic.pdf) is the Library of Congress system. I think maybe that plus Ryding would be enough for you to write bidirectional conversion. There are some standards which avoid the problematic digraphs *dh, th, sh, gh, kh* which could be read as a biconsonantal sequence as well, but they is not as popular (see Wright's grammar, Wehr's dictionary). Thus, γ could be ġ and ʃ can be ś, but both Wehr's and Wright's systems resort to underlining, which is not a computationally easy option. I prefer biting the bullet and using θ, ð, γ, š, ymmv.

Comment: Of course your book is $300 to buy :( haha

Comment: There is the Icelandic pirate version, and about $35 for used paperback versions. But, yeah.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few major issues you're running into. None of them are unsolvable! But I'd recommend reading up more on the phonology and morphology of Arabic too; it'll help with some of these.

First, certain Arabic letters can represent either vowels or consonants. The letter ي, for example, can be a long high front vowel `/iː/` (often romanized *ee*) or a palatal approximant `/j/` (often romanized *y*). This is why you're having trouble with إِيَّاكَ—the first letter is `/ʔi/`, the second is `/jja/`, the third is `/aː/`, and the fourth is `/ka/`, so I would romanize it as something like *iyyāka*. (Word-initial glottal stops are often ignored in romanization because Arabic words can't start with a vowel, so leaving them off doesn't add any ambiguity.)

Second, the definite article *al* is very weakly pronounced. The *a* is generally dropped when preceded by a vowel, and the *l* can assimilate to a following coronal consonant (look up "sun and moon letters" for the details). This is why الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ, underlyingly something like *al-raħmāni al-raħeemi*, has a surface form more like *ar-raħmānir-raħeemi*. (When you see a shaddah on the first consonant after the definite article, that's usually a good sign that the *l* has assimilated into it—Arabic words can't naturally start with a geminate.)

Third, at some point Arabic lost all word-final short vowels. Fully vocalized works sometimes indicate those vowels anyway, because in Classical Arabic they mark noun case (among other things), but in modern Arabic they won't be pronounced.

If you take these into account, your output will look a lot more like what Quran411 has.

Comment: Wow, so much more complicated than anticipated! Do you have a good reference in mind? Going to try out _A reference grammar of Modern Standard Arabic_ like recommended :)

Comment: @LancePollard As far as I know, that's the standard reference grammar, so it's a good place to start.